# API call to IBM MaaS360 in python not working

Tags: reactjs, backend, openstack-python-api

I'm building a React app that uses a Python backend to handle the API calls.  I just keep getting errors when I try to access the API data.  The credentials (hardcoded but removed) are double-checked and correct.  I've never accessed APIs that required authentication/tokens and I am a little stuck at the moment.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import os
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r'*': {'origins': '*'}})

# Your provided credentials
# Deleted for this question


# Test route that returns a simple string on the page
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World! This is the MaaS360 API Proxy.'

# Check the response status code and raise an exception if it's not 200


def check_response_status(response):
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            f"API call failed with status code {response.status_code}: {response.text}")
    if response.status_code == 500:
        error_message = response.json().get(
            'authResponse', {}).get('errorDesc', 'Unknown error')
        raise Exception(
            f"API call failed with status code 500: {error_message}")
    elif response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            f"API call failed with status code {response.status_code}: {response.text}")

# Fetches the data from the MaaS360 API


def fetch_maas360_data():
    try:
        auth_url = f'{api_base_url}/auth-apis/auth/1.0/authenticate/{billing_id}'

        auth_data = f'''<authRequest>
                        <maaS360AdminAuth>
                            <billingID>{billing_id}</billingID>
                            <platformID>{platform_id}</platformID>
                            <appID>{app_id}</appID>
                            <appVersion>{app_version}</appVersion>
                            <appAccessKey>{app_access_key}</appAccessKey>
                            <userName>{username}</userName>
                            <password>{password}</password>
                        </maaS360AdminAuth>
                        </authRequest>'''

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
        }

        auth_r = requests.post(auth_url, headers=headers, data=auth_data)
        check_response_status(auth_r)

        auth_response_content = auth_r.content.decode('utf-8')
        auth_token = ET.fromstring(
            auth_response_content).find("authToken").text

        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'MaaS token "{auth_token}"',
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
            'x-maas360-tenant-id': billing_id
        }
        api_url = f'{root_ws_url}/deviceapis/devices/1.0/search/{billing_id}'
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
        check_response_status(response)
        devices_xml = ET.fromstring(response.content)

        devices_list = []
        for device in devices_xml.findall('device'):
            device_name = device.find('deviceName').text
            platform_name = device.find('platformName').text
            maas360_device_id = device.find('maas360DeviceID').text
            user_name = device.find('username').text  # Changed variable name
            last_reported = device.find('lastReported').text
            device_status = device.find('deviceStatus').text

            devices_list.append({
                'id': maas360_device_id,
                'name': device_name,
                'os': platform_name,
                'username': user_name,  # Changed variable name
                'lastReported': last_reported,
                'deviceStatus': device_status
            })

        check_response_status(response)

        return devices_list

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data from MaaS360 API: {e}")
        return [{'error': f"Error fetching data from MaaS360 API: {e}"}]


# Route that returns the data from the MaaS360 API
@app.route('/api/maas360')
def maas360():
    data = fetch_maas360_data()

    if 'error' in data:
        return jsonify(data), 500
    else:
        return jsonify(data)


# Run the Flask app.  Debug mode is enabled so that the server will reload and the name is set to the name of the file
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting Flask server...")
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run curl, I get this: "error": "Error authenticating with MaaS360 API:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='services.m1.maas360.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /auth-apis/auth/1.0/authenticate/1180218 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x103c303a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))"
```

I tried to use Postman, but have never used it and ran into issues setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be missing an equal sign in your Authorization header. I have it like so:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"MaaS token="{authorizationToken}
```

EDIT: On second glance it seems your error is occurring at the Auth stage, before the line of code I reference is even reached.

Your headers and body all look correct so the only thing I could imagine is something being wrong with your URL; the base URL should be: `https://services.fiberlink.com/...`

Your error message was mentioning some other URL, so perhaps that was the issue.